# Unable to retrieve $_SESSION variable in include function of PHP

Tags: php, forms, session

I have two files:

**RedirectionTarget.php**

```
<?php
echo '<p>APPROVAL FOR CUSTOMER PURCHASE</p>';
echo "Currently cpaUpdResults:".$_SESSION['cpaUpdResults'];
include('RedirectionSrc.php');
echo "Currently cpaUpdResults:".$_SESSION['cpaUpdResults'];
if (isset($_SESSION['cpaUpdResults']) && !empty($_SESSION['userid'])) {
  if ($_SESSION['cpaUpdResults']) {
    echo "<p>Records was updated successfully ".$_SESSION['cpaUpdResults']."</p>"; 
  } else {
    echo "<p>Error! Please retry again".$_SESSION['cpaUpdResults']."HHHH</p>"; 
  }//
}//
?>
```

**RedirectionSrc.php:**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $id = $_POST['pidForApproval'];
  $remarks = $_POST['remarkstxt'];
  $resultOfUpdate = $remarks;
  $_SESSION['cpaUpdResults'] = $resultOfUpdate;         
  header("Location:RedirectionTarget.php");
  exit();
}
?>
<form class="approvalForm" action="RedirectionSrc.php" method="post">
  <div class="R01C01 formCell">
    <label for="remarkslbl">Annual value:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="R01C02 formCell">
    <div class="value">RM1000.10</div>
    <select name="approval" id="approval">
      <option value="">--Click here to view approve or reject--</option>
      <option value="approved">Approved</option>
      <option value="rejected">Rejected</option>
    </select>
    <label for="remarkslbl">Remarks:</label>
    <textarea id="remarkstxt" name="remarkstxt" rows="5" cols="70" maxlength="1000" placeholder="Click here to type remarks"></textarea>
    <span class="cm_char" id="char_disp"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="hidden" id="pidForApproval" name="pidForApproval" value="<?php echo "$pid"; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="approvalType" name="approvalType" value="cpurchase">
</form>
```

What I am trying to do is to fill up a form defined in RedirectionSrc.php but included in `RedirectionTarget.php`. After filling up the form, I submit the form and the `RedirectionSrc.php` processes it and then sends it back to RedirectionTarget.php, where I retrieve from the `$_SESSION['cpaUpdResults']` variable values and display them. My problem is that I can't retrieve the value I stored in `$_SESSION['cpaUpdResults']` found in RedirectionSrc.php. I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: You used `session_start()` ? For more look at the doc (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Yes I have, I have included in the RedirectionTarget.php, I didn't include in the posting above.

Comment: Have you put "session_start()" before ANY output?

Comment: And do you have proper PHP error reporting and display of errors enabled? (Yay, we have to go through _all_ the classics again …)

Comment: I couldn't include the session_start() in the RedirectionSrc.php file for when I do so, there is an error whenever  I reload RedirectionTarget.php. The error reads:  Notice: session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring in ....

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` is missing in both files. Without that the Session Variables will not be accessible.

Comment: Take a look in the comments of the question :-)

Comment: But why would you post a code question, while missing parts of the essential script? That does not make any sense.